# Overwriting metadata of a File with other in a FileInfo object c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, metadata, overwrite, fileinfo

Is it possible to overwrite the metadata of a file with other from a FileInfo object using C#? For example, I restore a file from a server and the server returns to me the file and the metadata. I save the file and then overwrite the metadata.

Thank you!

Comment: is this just straight `XML` data.. if so I do not see why you can't overwrite the data and save it.. can you show an example of the meta data format..?

Comment: no it isn't. The server sends them with a binary serialization of a FileInfo object which I deserialize. How can I assign them to the object?

Comment: can you not deserialize that data and then serialize it back.. just wondering

Comment: No no I mean... I correctly deserialize the metadata into a FileInfo object, then I want to write that object onto the associated file. For example I create a file and I receive from the server that the lastWriteTime is = "x", I want to mark that file as if the last write time is x.